# unable to establish connection b/w dependency track and jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying establish connection b/w `Jenkins` and `dependency track` . `Jenkins`, i have mentioned track url but i'm getting connection failed error. And I have added api token. please let me know where im missing?
[enter image description here][1]

please check image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw8zt.png

Comment: Typically, Jenkins is running on `localhost:8080`. Per [](https://plugins.jenkins.io/dependency-track/#plugin-content-global-configuration), "**Dependency-Track URL**: URL to your Dependency-Track instance." Seems you need a different url?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue, actually my bad, I was trying to connect with frontend(dependency track dashbaord) dashbaord IP:8080 instead Dependency-track-api which is running on 8081 port. so After changing port number 8080 to 8081 its working